# UIActivityIndicator not appearing in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios4, uiactivityindicatorview

I had successfully implemented activity indicator in my app, was working properly on simulator as well as on device also. Recently I upgraded my Device's OS from 4 to 5. since than I cannot see activity indicator which was appearing earlier.

My simulator supports is till OS 4.2 only, and it displays activity indicator properly. On device it not showing may be because of OS 5.

I have used IB to create activity indicator.

Thanks,
Jitesh

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the `hidesWhenStopped` property is set to `YES`, and the activity indicator is not animating.

Either set `hidesWhenStopped` to `NO` (to show it all the time), or make sure you call:

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: it still not displaying on the device

Answer (score 1):

Just check the style properties, in some cases the white and gray doesn't work, like in ios 5 the below style is workable for me.

```
activityStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
```

Comment: I added above line, but it still not displaying it on device, on simulator it works as i want.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work---

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator; //declare it as globaly

   CGFloat width = 40;
    CGFloat height = 40;
    CGRect centeredFrame = CGRectMake(500, 150, width, height);
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:centeredFrame];
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
```